# Strange 403 header response

Tags: headers, blog

I am receiving a strange 403 header response on the blog part of one of my sites. The site is accessible in the browser and works perfectly but googlebot, Moz and other checkers return a redirect from no trailing slash to trailing slash, then a 403 header.

There are no redirects that affect this, I've refreshed the htaccess and flushed the permalinks.

It only appears to affect the `/blog/` page of the site, the rest of the site comes back clean.

Does anyone know why my `/blog/` would return a 403 in my header?